# GCC allows access to private static member

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

This code works on GCC but not clang.

```
class Base
{
    static constexpr int PRIVATE = 1;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    template <class T>
    int bar( T & t )
    {
        return PRIVATE;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    int i = 3;
    d.bar(i);
}
```

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/g/qPJ47p

In the case of a private member function, GCC correctly detects the attempt to access a private member if the template function is instantiated, but otherwise does not. Clang detects the attempt even when the template function is never instantiated.

However, when using a private static constexpr variable, GCC (up to the latest 8.1) fails to stop private access even if the template function is instantiated. Clang correctly (?) complains.

Question: which of the two compilers is Standard-compliant in this situation?

It seems to me that GCC can't be right in allowing access to a private static constexpr variable. Yet at the same time it doesn't seem like an overly complicated issue, but it isn't in the latest GCC: that makes it seem intentional.

Much thanks to [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) for his clear and thorough answer. According to his suggestion I've made a more comprehensive list of test cases and narrowed it down to the `static` specifier causing the problem for GCC. See this Godbolt link for more detail: https://godbolt.org/g/A3zCLk

```
Comparison of GCC and Clang:

Private member    | GCC         | Clang

static const      | accept      | reject
static constexpr  | accept      | reject
static            | accept      | reject
const             | instantiate | reject
no-specifiers     | instantiate | reject
static function   | instantiate | reject
function          | instantiate | reject

("instantiate" means GCC rejects it upon template instantiation)
```

Comment: "doesn't seem like an overly complicated issue" -- this statement is rarely true, when it comes to modern C++.

Comment: I don't think that's right, Anton. If I remove `static constexpr` (or even just the `constexpr`), I get an error (in both gcc 8.1 and the trunk).

Comment: Apologies, spoke too soon and didn't test properly. Yes, if you make the variable non-static, it will work just fine. So `static const` and `static constexpr` cause this problem.

Comment: FWIW, Anton has now raised an issue on gcc bugzilla - see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85943 for details.

Comment: It's a dup of https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58740, but perhaps with a bit more detail than the #58740.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This *definitely* looks like a bug since whether it's an instantiated template function or a real function should have no bearing on accessibility of private members in the base class. If you change your code to:

```
int bar(int&) {
    return PRIVATE;
}
```

then it rightly complains:

```
testprog.cpp: In member function 'int Derived::bar(int&)':
testprog.cpp:3:26: error: 'constexpr const int Base::PRIVATE' is private
     static constexpr int PRIVATE = 1;
                          ^
testprog.cpp:9:16: error: within this context
         return PRIVATE;
                ^
```

I would just [raise this as a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) on `gcc`. If they *do* have a different view on its validity, they will let you know about it.

And, for when you *do* file the bug, I'd suggest using the absolute minimalist example that works, it'll make it much easier for them to debug. I got that down to:

```
class Base {
    static constexpr int PRIVATE = 42;
};
struct Derived : public Base {
    template <class T> int bar(T) {
        return PRIVATE;
    }
};
int main() {
    Derived d;
    return d.bar(1);
}
```

You may also want to indicate the various possibilities for declaring `PRIVATE` and their effect on `gcc` and `clang` (trunks as of this question):

```
                                gcc       clang
                              --------   --------
static constexpr int          accepted   rejected
static const int              accepted   rejected
const int                     rejected   rejected
int                           rejected   rejected
```

Using a non-templated function instead (as mentioned above):

```
int bar(int) {
    return PRIVATE;
}
```

seems to result in `gcc` "behaving" itself:

```
                                gcc       clang
                              --------   --------
static constexpr int          rejected   rejected
static const int              rejected   rejected
const int                     rejected   rejected
int                           rejected   rejected
```

So, if this is *indeed* a `gcc` problem, I'd be thinking that there's some interaction between `static` and templates which is causing the issue.

Comment: forgive my ignorance. perhaps this has something to do with [const static integral members are in namespace scope](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.static.data#3)?

Comment: @codekaizer, if you're referring to the text "If the member is declared with the constexpr specifier, it may be redeclared in namespace scope with no initializer (this usage is deprecated; see [depr.static_constexpr])", I don't think that means the *compiler* may move the declaration, it means you can do *another* declaration explicitly. Since we're not actually doing that, I'm not sure it has an impact here.

Comment: Wow: thank you for the thoroughness. I will add also another to your list: `static int    accepted    rejected`

Comment: I've added a listing of test cases and a table like gcc/clang comparison into the question text as well as the repro example. Unfortunately I'd already reported the bug on GCC so I'll have to add my improved test cases as a comment: hope it does not annoy them too much to have separate comments. Next time I'll hold off on reporting the bug until it's properly written!

Answer (score 0):

apologize this is not an answer but maybe a related issue:

```cpp
//g++ 4.8.4 compiles, g++ 5.4 fix it so it correctly fails to compile.
template<size_t N>
class T{
  public:
    constexpr static size_t m = N;
};

class A{
  constexpr static int a = 10;
};

namespace{
  auto t = T<A::a>::m;
}

int main(){
  cout <<  t << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

i have not found the bug number yet.